# How do I do a Big Air?

Tags: trials-fusion

In a *Trials Fusion* Big Air Skill Game, how do you make a good big air? I can't seem to make it over the hump of the big hill and am ending up in the 20-40 meter range which isn't even good enough for 90m for a Silver. I am hitting Y and the end of the jump as the game suggests, but it's not making much of a difference.

Do I need a better bike, or do I need to do something else to get air?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get silver, but not quite gold. move the left stick forward and back real quick at the beginning to do a little bunny hop over that initial mound. then hit y to bail about at the middle of the last platform while shifting all your weight forward at the end. Will return if I can figure out how to get gold!

Comment: This is the strategy I adopted, I managed to JUST squeeze a gold medal after a few tries, I think my best was about 116 metres.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this with the Roach, none of the other bikes are allowed.

My tactic is to tap the accelerator at the start so you just roll over the initial bump and get maximum acceleration down the slope. You may need to lean forward a little to keep your front wheel down.

Just as the slope levels out lean back very briefly then forward quickly to get some forward momentum for your rider, then bail out just before the bike reaches the end of the ramp.

Once in the air I maintain a death grip on R2 and up+right on the stick, I'm not sure it helps but it does seem to keep you in the air a little longer.

Sometimes it goes horrifically wrong (hey, it's Trials) but I've beaten the platinum distance of 135m a couple of times like this.

It makes more sense to see the button movements in action so I've posted a replay of a platinum run for this on YouTube which shows them:

You can also watch the best riders replays. Simply go to the leaderboards for the event, switch to the "Overall" list and view the replays from the top few players to see what they do.

Answer (score 1):

when you get to the second to last square on the ramp push left to lean back then hit forward real fast and hit the bail button in the middle of the last square on the ramp this is how i got the gold at 136.243 m